# Filter out remnant of previous data of variable length in a fixed length array

Tags: c, arrays, arduino, microcontroller

I try to make a packet sniffer with a TSS463C VAN datalink controller using Arduino. I can assign a memory location for a received message buffer, and the maximum data length which can be received. There are multiple message types, each with a different length, but the max length is 30 bytes. Unfortunately I don't know the incoming message length, so I created an array with a length of 30 bytes as my buffer.

My problem is that if a shorter message follows a longer message, the registers in the controller contain garbage past the end of the current message; specifically, the remains of the previous data received.

Re-writing of these registers in the controller takes time, which I would like to avoid.

So my question is how can I strip this "garbage" from the array in the fastest way?

Example:

```
5E 41 82 20 1F 95 6A  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
4D 41 83 8A 21 40 3D 54  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
5E 41 82 20 1F 95 6A 54  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
                     ^^
```

The **54** in the third message is garbage from the previous message. The last 2 bytes are checksum (95 6A) so if any part of the message changes, then this will change too.

**Update**

As I mentioned it is a packet sniffer application, so unfortunately I do not have control what is written into the registers of the controller. I just read their values(however I can write it if I want). Some messages is 6 bytes long, some 12 but the maximal length is 30. The message format is also fixed (I do not have control over it), and start with an ID byte some DATA bytes and 2 bytes CHECKSUM which is computed from ID and DATA bytes. There are 25 types of messages I think, each with a fixed header, which does not contain the length.

I was thinking about the following:
At startup I set all the registers to zeros, and start reading them periodically. I declare two arrays (previousData and currentData). I overwrite the previousData with the values of the currentData if they are different (and send them to my PC via serial port). I will compare the elements of the two arrays from backwards. Where the values of the arrays are not identical that is where the currently read message ends. (If the ID or the DATA changed then the CHECKSUM will change too.)

Comment: You have to keep track of how many bytes you've written into the buffer, and just ignore the rest.

Comment: or, since i can't quite tell whether you need to do this, you could use the tracked size to zero out anything between the end of the message and the end of the array, if required

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean, I don't know how many bytes get written into the buffer of the hardware. (Just the length of the previous one read out)

Comment: How do you know where the checksum starts when you're parsing the message?  Are you just reading until you encounter 00h?  What happens if a valid checksum contains a 00h byte?  I guess I don't understand what you expect to do with the message if you don't know where it ends.

Answer (score 0):

The standard options that are available to you include:

1. Fixed-size messages. Instead of a MAX size of 30 bytes, make EVERY message some fixed size (maybe 30), and compute your checksum over that. This way, the whole buffer gets overwritten.
2. Start messages with header info reporting the size. In some implementations, you might include the checksum in the header, to allow you to save a few bits.
3. Clear the buffer when it's read. You say you don't like this because of the time it takes, but you're going to have to pay a tax for accuracy one way or another.
4. Pad incoming messages with zeros or some type of [guard bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guard_byte). (Related to user3386109's comment, *You have to keep track of how many bytes you've written into the buffer, and just ignore the rest.*)

That's all you've got to work with. Without knowing more about your system design and limitations, I can't recommend one over another.

Comment: I added some clarification (or I hope so) to the question. As I wrote unfortunately the message size and format is out of my control, so that crosses out 1 and 2. Number three is a possible solution, but it is way too slow. Number for is also possible but I have to search for a byte combination which is not used by the protocol.

Answer (score 0):

To minimize cycles, I would take this approach:

After data enters buffer/registers, start read loop through them.
Test if byte is zero
If not zero 'read/move' data byte then set the location to zero
Continue through buffer/registers
When byte is zero, break out of loop.

This way you only test buffer/register contents once, you don't need to keep count of how many bytes came in and you minimize the number of 'set to zero' steps.